# What are other uses for a pizza stone?

Tags: equipment, pizza-stone

I recently acquired a pizza stone to use for baking bread. Other than pizza and bread, are there other uses for it in the kitchen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use mine as a heat shield in my grill to create indirect heat for slow smoked BBQ. I also use it to cook pizza on my grill, but that's not really a different use.

Answer (score 13):

A pizza stone can help an older or cheaper oven hold temperature as it will retain heat because of its mass, releasing it when the thermostat turns off the coil and reducing the variability in oven temperature. So, keep your pizza stone in the oven.

Answer (score 10):

Baking bread, pita, crusty French, crusty Italian, etc.

Was in a wonderful restaurant in Shanghai where they brought out very hot stones on wooden trays with holders for food on the side which (in my instance) held the largest shrimp I've ever seen and a large assortment of vegetables.  We cooked the food on the hot stone and had a great old time, what fun!  Ended up with only minor burns:)

There are probably a lot of other uses depending on how porous the stone is; if it is granite or something like that, use it for broiling steak after the stone is hot; wouldn't have to flip the steak.

Let your mind wander...not too far though; soup, I'm pretty sure, wouldn't work.

Comment: A good point about cooking meats on stone ... but I'd beware of the broiler; heating from only one side is more likely to crack the stone, and depending on the stone, could do so explosively.  If you're going to put it under the broiler, it's likely a good idea to pre-heat it first in a 'regular' oven (heat from top & bottom).

Answer (score 5):

Ours is good for cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Heston Blumenthal took all of the racks out of his oven and placed the stone in vertically against the side of the oven and used it as a makeshift tandoor oven to cook naan bread in it.