# Should I preheat glass and ceramic pans before baking bread?

Tags: baking, bread

I never bake a loaf of bread before and I would like to bake a no-knead bread. For your information, I have an electric oven, a glass and ceramic pans. Should I preheat the glass and ceramic pans in the oven before baking?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the pans are made for the oven (e.g. Pyrex or a similar brand), I would say no.  At least, I never do.

Also, unless a recipe specifically calls for it, I think you are risking overcooking the outside of the loaf, especially with glass baking dishes.

If you are worried about some sort of thermal shock cracking the dish, I think this would be more likely to occur if you have a hot dish into which you pour cold batter, and put it right back in the oven.  The water in the batter will suck heat away from the inside, while the oven is adding even more heat to a hot exterior.  This temperature difference is the kind of thing that can lead to thermal shock and cracking.

So, no, I would not suggest you preheat the dishes unless specifically told to by a recipe.

Comment: also, you may want to see this post: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/baking-in-glass-loaf-pan?rq=1